# Horizontal alignment in control seems to be ignored on all but the last item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have a custom radio button based on togglebutton:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ToolbarRadioButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
   <Setter Property="Width" Value="60"/>
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="60"/>
   <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
       <Setter.Value>
           <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                   <iconPacks:PackIconModern Kind="{Binding TbIcon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=RadioButton}}"
                                             Height="30" Width="35" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding TbText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=RadioButton}}" FontSize="12"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
               </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

I use this control to create four toggle/radio buttons. I've horizontal centered the items in datatemplate, but I end up with this:

[image]

Forecast and its icon seem to be centered, but the others are partially left-aligned.  They all use the same control so shouldn't they all be centered?

EDITS FOR CLARITY:
It doesn't matter which order I put them in, Forecast is always the one that's aligned correctly.
There is no whitespace in the text nor is there whitespace in the images and all images are sized according to the control defined above.  Here's the implementation portion in case it's useful, though they're all the exact same:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
    <customs:ToolbarRadioButton TbText="Day" TbIcon="CalendarDay" GroupName="calViewType" x:Name="dayOnOff"/>
    <customs:ToolbarRadioButton TbText="Week" TbIcon="CalendarWeek" GroupName="calViewType" x:Name="weekOnOff"/>
    <customs:ToolbarRadioButton TbText="Month" TbIcon="CalendarMonth" GroupName="calViewType" x:Name="monthOnOff" IsChecked="True"/>
    <customs:ToolbarRadioButton TbText="Forecast" TbIcon="PeopleMultiple" GroupName="calViewType" x:Name="forecastOnOff"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: What happens if you change the order of the bound collection? Is it always only the last one that's aligned correctly, or is it always Forecast that's the only one?

Comment: It's always Forecast that's correct no matter the order

Comment: But, there's nothing different in the implementation between Forecast and the others

Comment: Then it's nothing to do with your binding. You should update your question with that point as it's important. Have you checked that the images don't have some white space on the right? Either that or the text you are binding to the TextBlock doesn't have any trailing spaces.

Comment: The images are all sized the same according to the custom control above, it's from a common icon pack and I just checked, there is no whitespace in the images. There's no whitespace in the text, either. I'll update the question with all this.

Comment: Two suggestions: first try commenting out the TextBlocks and see if the icons line up, the comment out the icons and see if the TextBlocks line up. That might show you where the problem lies. Second, try manually writing out the XAML that you expect to be generated by the binding, and see if that works. If so, it tells you the problem is with the data you're using for binding

Comment: I tried all that and no luck.  I did, however, take the explicit height/width of the button out and it looks as expected, but now the buttons aren't all the same size which looks odd.

Comment: I figured it out while keeping the explicit height/width. Buttons have a property called HorizontalContentAlignment. I had tried to horizontal align the stackpanel that was holding the two items, but apparently I have to set the content to be horizontal aligned in the button itself. Thanks for sticking with me! Your comments aided in determining there was something more going on.

Comment: Glad you got sorted, and well done for posting your results to others can find them.

Answer (score 2):

For future readers: I figured out the answer by digging into the documentation on Button.  There is a property on buttons called HorizontalContentAlignment (and vertical, of course) that apparently needs to be set to align the visual content. You can't set the HorizontalAlignment property of the item that is the content explicitly; apparently, the button wants to do that for you.